# On click & hold for a duration alert something

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#action').click(function() {
            if(setTimeout(function() {}, 1000)) {
                alert("Hold");
            } else {
                alert("Click");
            }
        })

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='action'>Hello</button>
```

I'm trying to alert `Click` if i just clicked on the button, And alert `Hold` if i hold clicking the button for 2s,

The problem is that it always alerts `Hold` after clicking.

How to fix that And how to count the time of holding the button exactly?

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding how `setTimeout` works.

Comment: @SLaks I guess so, I also thought that by typing `setTimeout(2000)` or `setTimeout() == 2000` but didn't work either.

Comment: Every press of the mouse button will eventually be released, so there will always be a "click". However, the user may move the pointer off of the element before releasing. What you need to do is define the exact behavior you're want, and implement that, likely using multiple handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeoutId = 0;
  var functionCalled = false;

  $("#btn").on("mousedown", function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(btnHeld, 2000);
  }).bind("mouseup", function(e) {
    if (!functionCalled) {
      alert('clicked');
    }
    functionCalled = false;
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  });

  function btnHeld() {
    functionCalled = true;
    alert("hold");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `mousedown` event, set a timer for two seconds, then cancel that timer in the `mouseup` event.

Comment: In the mousedown i've tried if `mousedown` for `2000` and if `mousedown` for 1000` to emulate `click` but i get both the alerts after each other, the `1000` then `2000`

Comment: because you need to realize that setTimeout returns an id, it does not do what you think it does